# AWS Redshift left join keeps saying error

Tags: mysql, sql

This basic code keeps throwing an error:

```
select upper(contract_id) as tdr_contract_no, quantity_sold, upper(ordernbrpiid) as tdr_agcy_piid, total_price, sin_number as tdr_sin, desc_deliverable,
price_per_unit, name as tdr_name, Part_number as tdr_part_no, unit_measure, date_created

from tdr.order_details as apple

Where  sin_number in ('132 8STLOC', '132 8RC', '132 8', '132 34STLOC', '132 34', '132 34RC',
'132 33STLOC', '132 33RC', '132 33', '132 32STLOC', '132 32RC', '132 32', '33411', '33411RC',
'33411STLOC', '33411REF', '511210RC', '511210STLOC',
'511210') AND date_created between '2021-01-01' and '2021-03-31'

left join
 
(select REPLACE(UPPER(TRIM(REPLACE(regexp_substr(contractnumber, '.*_'), '_', ''))), '-', '') as catalog_contract_no,
 contractnumber, vendorname, vendorPartNumber as catalog_pt_no, manufacturername as oem_name, uniqueitemidentifier,
 sin as catalog_sin, standardizedProductName, standardizedProductDescription, catalogmedianprice
 
 from edw.fasdata_source.xsb_src_enriched_stg) as catalog1

on apple.tdr_contract_no = catalog1.catalog_contract_no and apple.tdr_part_no = catalog1.catalog_pt_no
;
```

I don't see anything I'm doing wrong. Been looking at this for 30 minutes. The error:

```
ERROR [42601] [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 42601] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "left"
LINE 8: left join
        ^
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your left join happens after the where clause; it needs to be part of the from clause

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is an operator in the `FROM` clause.  The `WHERE` clause follows the from clause.

Comment: Thanks antlersoft.